# How to getting a value from DevExpress GridControl Gridview

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm looking for something like this :

```
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value != null
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: c# - winforms - devexpress

Comment: maybe if you looking something like this, you need this? what is wrong in your code? what error do you get?

Comment: Hello, I need the same code for Devexpress with gridControl

Comment: `gridControl.MainView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value != null`?

Comment: gridControl1.MainView.**CurrentRow**.Cells[0].Value != null (error, no method for CurrentRow)

Comment: I want to use this code to delete a specific row :
if ((gridView1.DataRowCount > 0) && (gridControl1.MainView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value != null))

Comment: Use `FocusedRowHandle`, `FocusedColumn` or `FocusedValue` properties. and your question is EXTREMELY UNCLEAR!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a certain cell in a GridView through the GetRowCellValue() method:

```
gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column) != null;
```

You can get the `rowHandle` by focusing on the desired row and using

```
int rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
```